# Mapbox with leaflet markercluster with huge geojson data

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, markerclusterer

I am using `mapbox` for plotting clusters on map.

I am following this example. 
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markercluster-multiple-groups/

In this example geojson file has 86 records

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/assets/data/stations.geojson
It works fine with this data.

But when I load geojson file with 1000 records it is giving me following error.

> "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
>   Script: https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.js:4".

Please advise me on this.

Thanks !!

Comment: Can you show us your geojson file in a gist or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Try converting your geojson to topojson, it can help on performance.

http://jeffpaine.github.io/geojson-topojson/

or command line:

https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference